# Proving convergence for given improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

How do you prove the integral $\int_0^1\lvert\ln(x)\rvert\mathrm dx$ converges? The integral is presented as one of the problems in an analysis textbook of mine. How could it be solved?

Comment: Try the substitution $x = e^t$.

Comment: Please avoid stating the problem only in the title; the body of the Question should be as self-contained as possible.  Such a brief post leaves your Readers wondering where you are in understanding the problem statement, ie. do you know which kind of "improper" integral is given, and what would make it "converge"?  More detailed signs of effort on your part are appreciated and help the Reader to respond in a useful vein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\displaystyle\int\ln x\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x=x\ln x -x$, we have
$$\int_\varepsilon^1\ln x\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x=x\ln x -x\,\Bigr\rvert_\varepsilon^1=x\ln x -x\,\Bigr\rvert_\varepsilon^1=-1-\varepsilon\ln\varepsilon+\varepsilon,$$
hence $\;\displaystyle\int_\varepsilon^1\lvert\ln x\rvert\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x= \int_\varepsilon^1(-\ln x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x=1+\varepsilon\ln\varepsilon-\varepsilon$, which tends to $1$ as $\varepsilon$ tends to $0$ (basic result: $\lim_{u\to 0} u\ln u=0$).

Comment: It should be remarked that changing the sign to the integral in order to integrate the absolute value only works if the function is a.e. negative in the integration domain, as is the case here. In general, it doesn't. For example, if I did that to $f(x)=x$….

Comment: Doesn't it go without saying?

Comment: Probably. But not surely. There might be inexperienced readers that do not notice the logarithm is negative on the whole of $[0,1]$ and, trying to justify that, think up of a general $|\int|=\int||$ law which evidently doesn't hold. AND do not think of my easy counterexample. Unlikely, yes. But better be sure we don't cause such errors in inexpert minds :).

Comment: I added a detail, which should be enough, I guess.

Comment: Yep, saw it, and it seems enough to avoid the potential trap :).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**
$$\int_0^1|\ln(x)|dx=-\int_0^1\ln(x)dx$$
and $$\int \ln(x)dx=x\ln(x)-x+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the indefinite integral (by parts) and take the limit.

Comment: That hint is not very useful unless you state or at least imply which part of the integrand is $u$ and which is $dv$. The absolute value also needs to be addressed, as well as the problematic endpoint.

Comment: @RoryDaulton "not very useful" depends on "to whom".

Comment: I mean to the OP, of course, whose ability to solve such problems is lower than yours. I agree you have a valid hint, it just seems to be too subtle for him. (Not meant to be a insult to him or you, just an observation of what is likely to succeed in communication.)

Comment: Igor is a professor of math so he can't be wrong.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo I think and hope you wrote that as a goof.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Of course. Since I don't know what the OP's level of prowess is, I don't what is the most useful, but this is a multi-objective optimization problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $  \displaystyle \int \ln (x)  dx = x\ln( x)  - x + C      $

Comment: Maybe this Question was not stated in the best way, but you have omitted addressing the crucial issue of what makes the integral improper and thus whether convergence is in doubt.